# how to extract part of string that did not match pattern

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I want to extract part of string that did not match pattern

My pattern matching condition is sting should be of length 5 and should contain only N or Y.

Ex:

```
NYYYY => valid

NY    => Invalid , length is invalid

NYYSY => Invalid. character at position 3 is invalid
```

If string is invalid then I want to find out which particular character did not match. Ex : In NYYSY 4th character did not match.

I tried with pattern matching in scala

```
val Pattern = "([NY]{5})".r
    paramList match {
     case Pattern(c) => true
     case _  => false
    }
```

Comment: What about something like `"NYCYNX"`? That's invalid for 3 different reasons. Do you need to report all 3 or just whatever test fails first?

Answer (score 3):

Returns a `String` indicating validation status.

```
def validate(str :String, len :Int, cs :Seq[Char]) :String = {
  val checkC = cs.toSet
  val errs = str.zipAll(Range(0,len), 1.toChar, -1).flatMap{ case (c,x) =>
               if      (x < 0)     Some("too long")
               else if (checkC(c)) None
               else if (c == 1)    Some("too short")
               else                Some(s"'$c' at index $x")
             }
  str + ": " + (if (errs.isEmpty) "valid" else errs.distinct.mkString(", "))
}
```

testing:

```
validate("NTYYYNN", 4, "NY")  //res0: String = NTYYYNN: 'T' at index 1, too long
validate("NYC",     7, "NY")  //res1: String = NYC: 'C' at index 2, too short
validate("YNYNY",   5, "NY")  //res2: String = YNYNY: valid
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that returns a list of `(Char, Int)` tuples of invalid characters and their corresponding positions in a given string:

```
def checkString(validChars: List[Char], validLength: Int, s: String) = {
  val Pattern = s"([${validChars.mkString}]{$validLength})".r

  s match {
    case Pattern(_) => Vector.empty[(Char, Int)]
    case s =>
      val invalidList = s.zipWithIndex.filter{case (c, _) => !validChars.contains(c)}
      if (invalidList.nonEmpty) invalidList else Vector(('\u0000', -1))
  }
}

List("NYYYY", "NY", "NNSYYTN").map(checkString(List('N', 'Y'), 5, _))
// res1: List(Vector(), Vector((?,-1)), Vector((S,2), (T,5)))
```

As shown above, an `empty` list represents a valid string and a list of `(null-char, -1)` means the string has valid characters but invalid length.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion which might suit your needs:

```
"NYYSY".split("(?<=[^NY])|(?=[^NY])").foreach(println) 

NYY
S
Y
```

This solution splits the input string at any point when either the preceding or following character is *not* a `Y` or a `N`.  This places each island of valid and invalid characters as separate rows in the output.

Comment: thank you. I would like to know which particular character at particular position is invalid. Ex : character at position 3 is invalid

Comment: Then honestly you should just iterate the string and check at each position if it be `N`, `Y`, or some other invalid value.  Regex can only do so much here.

Comment: The position of the false character can be determined by calling `length` on the prior group. Because length starts at 1 the index offset is build-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional regular expressions to detect the specific issue:

```
val Pattern = "([NY]{5})".r
val TooLong = "([NY]{5})(.+)".r
val WrongChar = "([NY]*)([^NY].*)".r

paramList match {
  case Pattern(c) => // Good
  case TooLong(head, rest) => // Extra character(s) in sequence
  case WrongChar(head, rest) => // Wrong character in sequence
  case _ => // Too short
}
```

You can work out the index of the error using `head.length` and the failing character is `rest.head`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with pattern matching each characters of the string without using any sort of regex or complex string manipulation.

```
def check(value: String): Unit = {
  if(value.length!=5) println(s"$value length is invalid.")
  else value.foldLeft((0, Seq[String]())){
    case (r, char) =>
      char match {
        case 'Y' | 'N' => r._1+1 -> r._2
        case c @ _ => r._1+1 -> {r._2 ++ List(s"Invalid character `$c` in position ${r._1}")}
      }
  }._2 match {
    case Nil => println(s"$value is valid.")
    case errors: List[String] => println(s"$value is invalid - [${errors.mkString(", ")}]")
  }
}

check("NYCNBNY")
NYNYNCC length is invalid.

check("NYCNB")
NYCNB is invalid - [Invalid character `C` in position 2, Invalid character `B` in position 4]

check("NYNNY")
NYNNY is valid.
```